# How to disable the SameSite by default cookies in Google chrome by using Registry Policies or by Script

Tags: google-chrome, scripting, google-chrome-devtools, same-origin-policy

How do I disable the `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies` by using registry policies in windows or by script?

[image]